# Htaccess redirect по маске

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

Возможно ли редиректить по слову?
Например кулхацкер, пытаясь найди адрес админки на сайте, перебирает с помощью брута все адреса админок популярных cms (наивный:]). 
Так вот собственно сабж. Можно ли редиректить, если в адресе встречается слово *admin*, ну и его вариации. 
Гугл не затащил.

Comment: вопрос с точки зрения кулхацкера или вебмастера? кого куда редиректить? по какой маске?

Comment: WAT? что за нелепый вопрос. вебмастера конечно. зачем кулхацкеру себя редиректить с ломаемого сайта? в вопросе вроде бы все наглядно объяснил. Если это ускорит ответ.. Кулхацкер, набирает в строке например site.ru/wp-admin.php. Такого адреса не существует и его кидает на 404. И так далее он перебирает примитивной софтиной порядки 2000 адресов. Еще раз вопрос: возможно ли со страниц с адресом, в которых встречается слово admin, редиректить куда либо. Ну например на страницу с где запишется его ip, юзерагент и тд и тп и пропишется ему бан:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[да можно.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> Syntax:    RewriteCond TestString CondPattern
>
> REQUEST_URI
>
> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

REQUEST_URI

Часть URI, типа "/index.html". Эта переменная не включает строку поиска (после знака вопроса в строке типа "/index.html?search=term"), для обработки поиска существует отдельная переменная - QUERY_STRING .

> Remember: CondPattern is a perl compatible regular expression with some additions:

Помните: *CondPattern* это регулярное выражение perl c некоторыми дополнениями.

---

к счастью на SO подобный вопрос не продержался бы и пяти минут.

Comment: я ж не зря вопрос здесь задал ;) 
надеялся на готовое решение, потому что с апачевскими приблудами я дружу довольно плохо.

Comment: ох. готовое решение 100$/hr с логином на ваши сервера. Или подружитесь с "апачевскими приблудами"  используя подсказки или платите админам.